# Convert String to Integer List in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, type-conversion, android-room

I want to make function for typeconverter room. The original data is in List and i store it as String in database.

My code and the output is like this:

```
fun main() {
    val genreIds = listOf(28, 80)
    val stringFromList = fromList(genreIds)
    val stringToList = toList(stringFromList)
    
    println(genreIds) // output: [28, 80]
    println(stringFromList) // output: [28, 80]
    println(stringToList) // output: [91, 50, 56, 44, 32, 56, 48, 93]
}

fun fromList(genreIds: List<Int>): String = genreIds.toString()

fun toList(genreIdString: String): List<Int> {
    return genreIdString.map { it.toInt() }
}
```

I did try to use `split(",")` but it always give me error because of the `"["` and `"]"`. I want the output of toList function is `[28, 80]` too. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substring` to remove the first and last character:

```kotlin
fun toList(genreIdString: String): List<Int> =
    genreIdString
        .substring(1, genreIdString.length - 1)
        .split(", ")
        .map { it.toInt() }
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be a good idea to parse the input manually. I propose to use Kotlin Serialization [library](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/serialization.html) for this purpose.

Using it you can write as simple as:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

fun main() {
    val list = listOf(1, 2, 3)
    val str = Json.encodeToString(list)
    println(str) // "[1,2,3]"
    val list2: List<Int> = Json.decodeFromString(str)
    println(list2) // [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain why it is better other than writing?

Comment: @wiryadev Using the `toString()` method you don't control the output - the result will depend on the method implementation which might change in the future. You can use `toString()` for debug purposes but if you need to store some data it's better to choose the approach which will give you predictable output.

Comment: I like Konstantin's argument of defensive programming against implementation changes. As an alternative solution, if you know that the strings that your `toList` method receives were created by the `fromList` method, then you could change your `fromList` method to `genreIds.joinToString(", ", "[", "]")`. Combine this with the solution by Aplet123 or by me, and you won't have to depend on the implementation anymore. Then again, I don't think the `toString` implementation is likely to change, so I would suggest choosing the solution that is easiest to read.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `removeSurrounding` method to remove delimiters:

```kotlin
fun toList(genreIdString: String): List<Int> =
    genreIdString
        .removeSurrounding("[", "]")
        .split(", ")
        .map { it.toInt() }
```

I think this approach is better than using `substring` because it more clearly conveys your intent.